# opencart 3.0 dashboard error 500 after refreshing cache

Tags: php, sass, opencart, dashboard, scss-mixins

Good evening people.

Im having trouble fixing my opencart dashboard and searching around is proving futile.
Im faurly new to hosting and the opencart framework so please bear with.

I had been using opencart 3 for my webstore and was happy editing it through the dashboard. however, as I was dealing with an ssl issue, I read advice to clear my opencart cache. I did this by clicking on th refresh buttons for Theme and sass
inside the dashboard. Now I can open my dash board! when I want to access it I get a white screen or error 500.
I allowed errors in the admin php file and it tells me this;

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Scssc' not found in /home/cluster-sites/6/…

so I'm guessing I'm missing the Scssc class that's used for sass on the dashboard and without it my dashboard cannot open, 
My question is, can I reinstall or repair whatever file I need to reinstate my dashboard or rewrite the info (the Scssc class) that has gone missing since clearing the cache? any help would be appreciated as I'm on a deadline to get tons of products uploaded and the thought of starting again chills me to my core!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same here. I googled and found related issue on github:
[image]

About your issue: please double check your paths. Double check config.php in root and in admin.

Comment: Thanks for the update. i found that too. there were to many path issues. i reinstalled opencart and reconfigured in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Check you config.php and admin/config.php files. Make sure your paths are correct.